# Hot to set up zone files, DNS for a domain registered at gandi.net for heroku app

Tags: domains, dns, dns-servers

So I have hard time understanding what exactly I should do as most of the posts about this topic seem to be outdated because of some changes(?) heroku made. Currently I have everything set up according to all instructions I could find but still, when I go to `mydomain.gg` or `www.mydomain.gg` I get default gandi page stating that the domain has been registered at gandi.net.

Do I need to change my DNS servers which currently point to gandis servers? Also here's my zone file. The first line was automatically added for redirecting to www, I think.

```
@ 10800 IN A 217.70.184.38
www 10800 IN CNAME myapp.herokuapp.com
```

And here's my redirection set up:
[image]

Or maybe everything is

Answer (score 1):

```
@ 10800 IN A 217.70.184.38
www 10800 IN CNAME myapp.herokuapp.com.
```

Seems I was missing dot at the very end of the second line which made it interpret as a subdomain of my main domain.